# Problem due to 2-step verification

Tags: gmail, multi-factor-auth, verification

Signed up for 2-step verification for my Gmail account, but didn't like it so I turned it off; only I can no longer access my account from my Kindle. Seems there is a problem with the security to my account now.

How do I restore access to my Gmail account from my Kindle?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to revoke the application specific password which you had probably setup for your Kindle. Then reauthorize the device with username, password like earlier.

Here is Google's support [document](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1064203&topic=2784804&ctx=topic) on turning off two-factor authentication.

Edit: I misread your question and provided the answer which works when you have 2fA enabled!

My earlier answer:
You will have to generate application specific passwords to do that. These are different from your Google Account password and are different for different devices/applications. Follow Google's instructions given [here](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833) to generate the password(s).

Comment: He _switched off_ 2-step verification. Application specific passwords are only required if you have 2fA enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I just switched Iphones, use Gmail with two step verification and Exchange to connect my computer and my phone.  I COULDN'T GET MY EXCHANGE TO WORK on my new phone and searched all over the web.  Lots of others have this problem.  I want to post that I found the answer.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936

**Google discontinued Exchange as of 1/1/13.**  They have a new system now.**  It was grandfathered on my old phone, but if you switch, or run a re-install, it will wipe out the Exchange you had set up.  The new system is described really well in:

http://www.redmondpie.com/set-up-carddav-on-iphone-to-sync-google-gmail-contacts-without-exchange/

Make sure you use your google email address, not your "user name" under "user name".  Once I moved to cardDAV and calDAV, it worked just fine.

*** If you use Two Step Verification, just put in the application specific code instead of your regular Google password.  ****